# Get a command to ignore stuff in braces?

Tags: macros, biblatex

**Update:** @wipet's answer is nearly perfect, it seems like the only problem is that it doesn't work properly with `safeinputenc`: accented characters aren't capitalized properly and weird commands like `{\'\i}` throw all sorts of errors. That doesn't happen with `biblatex`'s own `\MakeSentenceCase`, for instance, so I'll leave this here in case someone has any ideas.

Another update: I get "missing `\endcsname` inserted" errors if I use {\LaTeX} in a field with @wipet's `smartuppercase` command.

---

I'm using biblatex and I did this:

`\DeclareFieldFormat{uppercase}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}`

So when I want to print a field in uppercase I can use `\printfield[uppercase]{title}`.

The problem is this always makes *everything* uppercase, and I want to ignore stuff in braces, so that, for instance, `{an Introduction to {LaTeX}}` is printed as "AN INTRODUCTION TO LaTeX". How can I do that?

---

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{blabla,
 title = {São {Paulo}}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[safeinputenc, backend=biber, bibstyle=standard]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}


\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\traceparam#1{\def\paramL{}\traceparamA #1\end}
\def\traceparamA{\futurelet\next\traceparamB}
\def\traceparamB{%
   \let\nexts=\undefined
   \expandafter\ifx\space\next \let\nexts=\traceparamS \fi
   \ifx\bgroup\next \let\nexts=\traceparamD \fi
   \ifx\end\next \let\nexts=\traceparamE \fi
   \ifx\nexts\undefined \let\nexts=\traceparamC\fi
   \nexts
}
\def\traceparamS{\addto\paramL{ }\afterassignment\traceparamA \let\next= }
\def\traceparamC#1{\addto\paramL{#1}\traceparamA}
\def\traceparamD#1{%
   \expandafter\addto\expandafter\paramL\expandafter
        {\expandafter\noexpand\csname ll:#1\endcsname}%
   \expandafter\def\csname ll:#1\endcsname{#1}%
   \traceparamA
}
\def\traceparamE\end{}

\def\smartuppercase#1{%
   \bgroup 
   \traceparam{#1}%
   \MakeUppercase{\paramL}%
   \egroup
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{uppercase}{\smartuppercase{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{\printfield[uppercase]{title}}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

My result:

[image: mwe]

While it should be "SÃO Paulo".

---

**Edit:**

I don't know if this might be useful: `biblatex` has a `\MakeSentenceCase` command that works the way I want it to, but it only capitalizes the first letter in a sentence and makes the rest lowercase. I tried to find how it's defined so maybe I'd be able to do something similar for an uppercase command, and I think this is the relevant part, but it makes no sense to me. I assume `mksc` stands for "make small case", and that's as far as I got.

```
\newrobustcmd*{\MakeSentenceCase}{%
  \@ifstar\blx@mksc@i\blx@mksc@ii}

\def\blx@mksc@i{%
  \ifdef\abx@field@langid
    {\xifinlist\abx@field@langid\blx@cmksc@lang
       {\blx@mksc@ii}
       {\@firstofone}}
    {\blx@mksc@ii}}

\long\def\blx@mksc@ii#1{%
  \begingroup
  \let\blx@tempa\@empty
  \let\blx@tempb\@empty
  \blx@mksc@init
  \protected@edef\@tempa{#1}%
  \expandafter\blx@mksc@parse\@tempa\blx@mksc@end}

\def\blx@mksc@init{%
  \blx@mkcp@init
  \def\blx@mkcp@nil{\noexpand\blx@mkcp@nil\noexpand}%
  \def\i{\blx@mkcp@nil\i}\def\j{\blx@mkcp@nil\j}%
  \def\do##1{%
    \ifx##1\relax
    \else
      \def##1{\blx@mkcp@nil##1}%
      \expandafter\do
    \fi}%
  \expandafter\do\@uclclist\relax}

\def\blx@mksc@parse{%
  \futurelet\@let@token\blx@mksc@eval}

\def\blx@mksc@eval{%
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mksc@end
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@end
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\bgroup
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@group
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\@sptoken
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@space
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@nil
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@getone
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@iec
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@getiec
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@bbl
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@gettwo
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@sgl
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@gettwo
  \fi
  \ifx\@let@token\blx@mkcp@dbl
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@getthree
  \fi
  \if\noexpand\@let@token\relax
    \expandafter\blx@mksc@cs
  \fi
  \blx@mksc@other}

\def\blx@mksc@end#1\blx@mksc@end{%
  \blx@mksc@eject
  \let\blx@mkcp@nil\noexpand
  \let\blx@mkcp@iec\noexpand
  \let\blx@mkcp@bbl\noexpand
  \let\blx@mkcp@sgl\noexpand
  \let\blx@mkcp@dbl\noexpand
  \let\MakeUppercase\relax
  \let\MakeLowercase\relax
  \protected@edef\blx@tempa{\endgroup\blx@tempa}%
  \blx@tempa}

\long\def\blx@mksc@group#1\blx@mksc@other#2{%
  \futurelet\@let@token\blx@mksc@ingroup#2&{#2}%
  \blx@mksc@endhead
  \blx@mksc@parse}

\long\def\blx@mksc@ingroup#1&#2{%
  \if\noexpand\@let@token\relax
    \blx@mksc@locase{{#2}}%
  \else
    \blx@mksc@nocase{{#2}}%
  \fi}

\def\blx@mksc@space{\def\blx@mksc@space##1\blx@mksc@other}
\csuse{blx@mksc@space} {%
  \blx@mksc@anycase{ }%
  \blx@mksc@endhead
  \blx@mksc@parse}

\long\def\blx@mksc@cs#1\blx@mksc@other#2{%
  \ifcat\noexpand~\noexpand#2%
    \blx@mksc@locase{#2}%
  \else
    \blx@mksc@nocase{#2}%
  \fi
  \blx@mksc@endhead
  \blx@mksc@parse}

\def\blx@mksc@getiec#1\blx@mksc@other#2#3#4{%
  \blx@mksc@other{#2#3{#4}}}

\def\blx@mksc@getone#1\blx@mksc@other#2#3{%
  \blx@mksc@other{#2#3}}

\def\blx@mksc@gettwo#1\blx@mksc@other#2#3#4{%
  \blx@mksc@other{#2#3#4}}

\def\blx@mksc@getthree#1\blx@mksc@other#2#3#4#5{%
  \blx@mksc@other{#2#3#4#5}}

\long\def\blx@mksc@other#1{%
  \blx@mksc@locase{#1}%
  \blx@mksc@endhead
  \blx@mksc@parse}

\def\blx@mksc@locase{%
  \appto\blx@tempb}

\def\blx@mksc@nocase{%
  \blx@mksc@eject
  \appto\blx@tempa}

\def\blx@mksc@anycase{%
  \ifx\blx@tempb\@empty
    \expandafter\appto
    \expandafter\blx@tempa
  \else
    \expandafter\appto
    \expandafter\blx@tempb
  \fi}

\def\blx@mksc@eject{%
  \ifx\blx@tempb\@empty
  \else
    \eappto\blx@tempa{\noexpand\MakeLowercase{\expandonce\blx@tempb}}%
    \let\blx@tempb\@empty
  \fi}

\def\blx@mksc@endhead{%
  \ifx\blx@tempb\@empty
  \else
    \eappto\blx@tempa{\noexpand\MakeCapital{\expandonce\blx@tempb}}%
    \let\blx@tempb\@empty
  \fi
  \let\blx@mksc@endhead\relax}
```

Comment: Please post a complete, compilable example complete with a suitable sample `.bib` entry.

Comment: As a temporary work around you could use the commands from `textcase.sty`. However, this would mean needing to tweak the contents of your `.bib` fields, so I only suggest it as a temporary work around.

Comment: @jon Thanks, for now I'm just typing stuff in uppercase myself when I need it, but I'm trying to write a custom style and it would be good to do it automatically with the `.bib` files people already have.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

May be you need something like this:

```
\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\traceparam#1{\def\paramL{}\traceparamA #1\end}
\def\traceparamA{\futurelet\next\traceparamB}
\def\traceparamB{%
   \let\nexts=\undefined
   \expandafter\ifx\space\next \let\nexts=\traceparamS \fi
   \ifx\bgroup\next \let\nexts=\traceparamD \fi
   \ifx\end\next \let\nexts=\traceparamE \fi
   \ifx\nexts\undefined \let\nexts=\traceparamC\fi
   \nexts
}
\def\traceparamS{\addto\paramL{ }\afterassignment\traceparamA \let\next= }
\def\traceparamC#1{\addto\paramL{#1}\traceparamA}
\def\traceparamD#1{%
   \expandafter\addto\expandafter\paramL\expandafter{\csname ll:#1\endcsname}%
   \expandafter\def\csname ll:#1\endcsname{#1}%
   \traceparamA
}
\def\traceparamE\end{}

\def\smartuppercase#1{%
   \bgroup 
   \traceparam{#1}%
   \uppercase\expandafter{\paramL}%
   \egroup
}

\smartuppercase{an Introduction to {TeX}}
```

**Edit:** If there are problems with accented characters then you can try to replace `\uppecase` by `\MakeUpercase` like this

```
%\uppercase\expandafter{\paramL}%
\MakeUppercase{\paramL}
```

and you must protect the generated csnames like this:

```
%\expandafter\addto\expandafter\paramL\expandafter{\csname ll:#1\endcsname}%
\expandafter\addto\expandafter\paramL\expandafter
   {\expandafter\noexpand\csname ll:#1\endcsname}%
```

Comment: Ah, that's almost perfect! The only problem is in `biblatex` it doesn't work with accented characters. I'm trying my example with `{São Paulo}` in the title and for me the "ã" still shows up in lowercase… and then in the biblatex package I'm trying to write it also throws a lot of errors (but that might be my fault).

Comment: Uhm, ok, the errors in my bibliography style are happening because I can't use your code in the `biblatex` `.bbx` file… so I think I'd have to create a `.sty` file? Anyway, the main problem now is that when I use `smartuppercase` with the `\DeclareFieldFormat` command the accented letters aren't affected. You were a huge help already, though, and I'm thinking this might be more of a `biblatex` specific problem. So maybe I should close this question and open a new one for that? Or should I keep going with this one? I didn't get the hang of the etiquette around here yet.

Comment: @danielbmarques The problem is that I don't use LaTeX, so I didn't test it. Maybe, you must use `\MakeUpercase` instead `\uppercase` primitive in my code. And then you must protect csnames by `\noexpand` because `\MakeUpercase` does an expansion. I'v added some ideas to my answer. But it is not tested (I don't use LaTeX biber and such things).

Comment: Well, the good news is that now the code works directly in my `.bbx` file. The bad news is that accented characters are still in lowercase, which is weird. `\DeclareFieldFormat{uppercase}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}` gives me "SÃO PAULO", `\DeclareFieldFormat{uppercase}{\smartuppercase{#1}}` gives me "SãO PAULO". I edited my question with something I found in the `biblatex_.sty` file, I don't know if it would make any sense to you. Thanks for the help. :)

Comment: @danielbmarques Your MWE (where only `\MakeUppercase` is used) does not work with `São Paulo` string. Biber generates `.bbl` with `\x{fffd}` instead `ã` and this yields to undefined control sequence. Please, upgrade your MWE in order to it works with accents first.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I forgot to add inputenc and all. Now I updated the MWE with your code already in it. Thanks again!

Comment: @danielbmarques I don't understand why do you set the option `safeinputenc` to biblatex. When it is used then biber generates obscure encoding of accents in its output `.bbl`. But if this option is removed then biber behaves normally: i.e generates normal UTF8 codes in `.bbl`. And `\smartuppercase` (from your MWE) is working.

Comment: There is simple explanation of your problem. When `safeinputenc` is used then biber generates `São Paulo` as `S\~{a}o Paulo`. So, `\smartuppercase` keeps `{a}` unchanged because `a` is hidden in braces. It does what we need.

Comment: Ah, interesting! I'm using `safeinputenc` because I'm trying to replace a `bibtex` style and people are already using `.bib` files that won't work correctly without it. I keep getting errors like "Package inputenc Error: Unicode char ÃÅ (U+301) not set up for use with LaTeX." Now I don't know if it's more reasonable to look for another way to solve this problem or to look for a way to make the `smartuppercase` command work with `safeinputenc`. Biblatex's `\MakeSentenceCase` command works fine, I don't know how they do it.

Comment: Now I've played around a bit and if I use `smartuppercase` with a title like `{pol{\'\i}tica}` it throws a lot of errors with or without `safeinputenc`. If I replace `smartuppercase` with `\MakeSentenceCase`, on the other hand, it works perfectly with `safeinputenc` and prints "Política". I'm sorry for complicating things, you've been a huge help already. For my own use I can work around these issues, but I'm trying to make something other people can use too.

Comment: Well, now I'm looking into it a little more and I have no idea why `abntex2cite` (the `bibtex` style I'm trying to replace) uses `{\'\i}` for "í". It seems like it should be just `{\'i}`, and then everything works properly without `safeinputenc`. It would still be useful to have a version of the command that works with `inputenc`, so I think I'll leave this question open a little longer in case someone else has any ideas, but I gave you the bounty (although it probably doesn't matter much to you), you were really a huge help, thanks. :)

Comment: Ah, another problem. If I use `{\LaTeX} ` in the title I get "missing \endcsname inserted" errors. Any ideas? It seems like it would be very risky to publish a style that uses this command, lots of things can cause problems. :/

Comment: @danielbmarques -- (Somewhat off-topic, I realize.) Regarding política, you should compare `\'\j` and `\'j` for other accents.

Comment: @danielbmarques Ad `{\TeX}`: use `ll:\detokenize{#1}` instead `ll:#1` (at two places in the code). Ad `{\'\i}`: don't use obscure encoding in 2016, we have Unicode today! This obscure encoding seems like computer prehistory. You cannot use one syntax `{}` to two different things.

Comment: @wipet Maybe you can help me with one more thing. I'm trying to do something similar to this to define a command that makes text both lowercase and small caps. I tried to use the same code as in your `\def\smartuppercase`, but instead of `\MakeUppercase{\paramL}` I used `\textsc{\MakeLowercase{\paramL}}`. But the whole text is printed in small caps, even if it's in braces (text in braces isn't made lowercase, though, which is right). Any ideas? I thought of opening another question, but I think it might be something easy to fix.

Comment: @danielbmarques You must replace `\traceparamD` macro by another. If I understand correctly, your wish is to auto-replace `\textsc{aaa bbb {ccc} ddd}` by `\textsc{aaa bbb \textrm{ccc} ddd}`. So, you can define `\def\traceparamD#1{\addto\paramL{\textrm{#1}}\traceparamA}`.

Comment: @wipet It didn't work. :/ I created [another question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309510/102699) to be able to explain it better and avoid so many comments here. If you can take a look when you have the time I'll be even more grateful. Thank you so much. :) http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/309510/102699