# How to preserve lowercase in curly bracket with \MakeUppercase in BibLaTeX?

Tags: biblatex

I use

```
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamegiven}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
\renewcommand*{\mkbibnamefamily}[1]{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
```

in my .bbx file to make a uppercase name. But for some author name, such as an organization name, I want to use curly bracket to preserve it, like

```
author = {{Online Computer Library Center, Inc.}},
```

How to fix it?

---

[Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307769/get-a-command-to-ignore-stuff-in-braces) is the same question.

Comment: The [same question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307769/8528) was just asked, but still awaits an answer.