# Get \textsc to ignore stuff in braces

Tags: macros

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307769/102699) allowed me to create an uppercase command that would ignore stuff in braces, so that `\smartuppercase{An introduction to {LaTeX}}` is printed as "AN INTRODUCTION TO LaTeX".

Now I want a command that does the same thing but turns text into both lowercase and small caps. I tried this:

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{blabla,
 title = {An introduction to {LaTeX}}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=standard]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\traceparam#1{\def\paramL{}\traceparamA #1\end}
\def\traceparamA{\futurelet\next\traceparamB}
\def\traceparamB{%
   \let\nexts=\undefined
   \expandafter\ifx\space\next \let\nexts=\traceparamS \fi
   \ifx\bgroup\next \let\nexts=\traceparamD \fi
   \ifx\end\next \let\nexts=\traceparamE \fi
   \ifx\nexts\undefined \let\nexts=\traceparamC\fi
   \nexts
}
\def\traceparamS{\addto\paramL{ }\afterassignment\traceparamA \let\next= }
\def\traceparamC#1{\addto\paramL{#1}\traceparamA}
%\def\traceparamD#1{\addto\paramL{\textrm{#1}}\traceparamA}% This doesn't work either
\def\traceparamD#1{%
   \expandafter\addto\expandafter\paramL\expandafter
        {\expandafter\noexpand\csname ll:#1\endcsname}%
   \expandafter\def\csname ll:#1\endcsname{#1}%
   \traceparamA
}
\def\traceparamE\end{}

\def\smartsc#1{%
   \bgroup 
   \traceparam{#1}%
   \textsc{\MakeLowercase{\paramL}}%
   \egroup
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{uppercase}{\smartsc{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{\printfield[uppercase]{title}}

\begin{document}
  \smartsc{An introduction to {LaTeX}}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the result is this:

[image: smartsc]

So the capitalization is preserved and "LaTeX" is printed with L, T and X in uppercase. But the A and the E are in small caps, while I want them to be regular lowercase letters. [In the comments to the question I mentioned above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307769/get-a-command-to-ignore-stuff-in-braces/308121?noredirect=1#comment751703_308121) @wipet (thank you!) suggested I try replacing `traceparamD` with the code that's commented out, but that still doesn't work… if I do that everything still shows up in small caps and the capitalization isn't preserved either:

[image: smartsc2]

Any ideas how I can keep "LaTeX" in that string just as it's typed, with the same capitalization and the regular font (no small caps)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

[image: LaTeX]

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{blabla,
 title = {An introduction to {LaTeX}}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=standard]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\long\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\traceparam#1{\def\paramL{}\traceparamA #1\end}
\def\traceparamA{\futurelet\next\traceparamB}
\def\traceparamB{%
   \let\nexts=\undefined
   \expandafter\ifx\space\next \let\nexts=\traceparamS \fi
   \ifx\bgroup\next \let\nexts=\traceparamD \fi
   \ifx\end\next \let\nexts=\traceparamE \fi
   \ifx\nexts\undefined \let\nexts=\traceparamC\fi
   \nexts
}
\def\traceparamS{\addto\paramL{ }\afterassignment\traceparamA \let\next= }
\def\traceparamC#1{\addto\paramL{#1}\traceparamA}
\def\traceparamD#1{%
   \expandafter\addto\expandafter\paramL\expandafter
        {\expandafter\noexpand\csname ll:#1\endcsname}%
   \expandafter\def\csname ll:#1\endcsname{\normalfont #1}%
   \traceparamA
}
\def\traceparamE\end{}

\def\smartsc#1{%
   \bgroup
   \traceparam{#1}%
   \textsc{\MakeLowercase{\paramL}}%
   \egroup
}

\DeclareFieldFormat{uppercase}{\smartsc{#1}}
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{\printfield[uppercase]{title}}

\begin{document}
  \smartsc{An introduction to {LaTeX}}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Ah, perfect, thank you! I really have to learn some TeX programming. I suspected it could work to add `\normalfont` somewhere in there, but I had no idea where and I was trying random places without success.